# Android samples' gradle files refer to a non-existent file

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build.gradle, sample

I've been trying to import and run the new Android samples, specifically **ArchitectureComponentsBasic** example. However, the gradle files refer to a file that has not been downloaded with the project.

In the app module's gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: '../versions.gradle' // <-- This file!
    addRepos(repositories)
    dependencies {
        classpath deps.android_gradle_plugin

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

the build script is applied from `../version.gradle` file.

And in the project's gralde file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
    buildToolsVersion build_versions.build_tools

..

dependencies {
    // Support libraries
    implementation deps.support.app_compat
    implementation deps.support.v4
    implementation deps.support.design

...

    androidTestImplementation deps.room.testing
    androidTestImplementation deps.arch_core.testing

    // Espresso UI Testing
    androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.core
    androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.contrib
    androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.intents

    // Resolve conflicts between main and test APK:
    androidTestImplementation deps.support.annotations
    androidTestImplementation deps.support.v4
    androidTestImplementation deps.support.app_compat
    androidTestImplementation deps.support.design
}
```

The versions are defined in a variable which is not in the file itself.

How do I get the file `versions.gradle` and run the sample project? Also will that resolve the undefined variables in the project's gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not download the entire repository, or you may have set your project up incorrectly.  the "`..`" in `../version.gradle` is telling the code to go up a folder in the file system.

[Here is the missing file.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/versions.gradle)  You may be able to just download it, and edit your gradle, or your might have to clone the whole project again.